# Combine multiple shell commands to create temporary table in sqlite3

Tags: shell, sqlite, applescript

Rather than create, and then drop a table in sqlite3, I would like to create a temporary table which is destroyed when you end your session.  Is it possible to combine the commands below so the temporary table is not destroyed by the semicolon ?

```
set databaseName to "test.db"
set tableName to "tempTable"
do shell script ("mkdir -p ~/Documents/Databases/ ; sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/" & databaseName & " \"create table if not exists " & tableName & "(First, Last);  \"")
do shell script ("sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/" & databaseName & " \"insert into " & tableName & " (First, Last) values('John', 'Doe'); \"")
```

How would I implement this version of it?

```
set databaseName to "test.db"
set tableName to "tempTable"
do shell script ("mkdir -p ~/Documents/Databases/ ; sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/" & databaseName & " \"create temp table " & tableName & "(First, Last);  \"")
do shell script ("sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/" & databaseName & " \"insert into " & tableName & " (First, Last) values('John', 'Doe'); \"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite accepts semicolon-separated statements itself.

```
do shell script ("sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/" & databaseName & " \" & ¬
    "create temp table " & tableName & " (First, Last); " & ¬
    "insert into " & tableName & " (First, Last) values('John', 'Doe'); " & ¬
    " -- other stuff here --" & ¬
    "select * from " & tableName & ";\"")
```

At some point it becomes easier to write it out as a separate script or possibly a here document than to build up a single huge `do shell script`, though.